# How can I obtain a Dataset result from a single query with multiple related tables?

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I have a query with multiple joined tables, this is a simple version, I have many such with further levels of joins:

```
SELECT        ApplicationField.OID, ApplicationField.FieldName, ApplicationField.Label, ApplicationField.DataType, ApplicationField.Length, ApplicationField.FieldType, ApplicationField.DefaultValue, ApplicationField.DataPrefix, 
                         ApplicationField.DisplaySequence, ApplicationField.TabNumber, ApplicationField.Required, ApplicationField.Hidden, ApplicationField.PasswordField, ApplicationField.Loopback, ApplicationField.ApplicationVersion, 
                         ApplicationField.OptimisticLockField, FieldQuery.QueryID, FieldQuery.ApplicationField, FieldQuery.ExecuteSequence, FieldQuery.MaxRows, FieldQuery.ReturnField, FieldQuery.QueryType
FROM            ApplicationField LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         FieldQuery ON ApplicationField.OID = FieldQuery.ApplicationField
WHERE(ApplicationField.ApplicationVersion = @versionOID)
ORDER BY ApplicationField.TabNumber, ApplicationField.DisplaySequence
```

How can I use a Datareader or DataAdapter using a single SQl statement that returns multiple related tables, keeping the tables separate in a dataset, so that I get separate tables for ApplicationFields and related FieldQueries? There may be multiple FieldQueries per Application Field, one to many relationship.

Comment: When you use JOINS in a query it does not separate each table into it's own DataTable, it returns one DataTable reflecting the results of your query. If you need to return separate results by table, you would need to write a separate query to return results from each individual table and then you can get it as a dataset. You would then need to check the column names in each datatable returned to verify you are working with the correct table, typically as far as I know a dataset is returned in the sequential order of the Select statements in your query or stored procedure.

Comment: [Add the tables individually then create a relationship](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: So, I sort of get that, but:  1.  If I run that query in the 'Query Builder' for a tableadapter, yes it returns a single table/flat result.  But it does have a column for what Table it originated from, so, somehow it HAS the information.    2.  Fine, if I need separate statements, so be it, but how can I JOIN them, so I get the sub table results only for the main table records selected.

Comment: There's no way (not even in SQL) to split a dataset into the original tables my dude. Once you query, the results are a "result set" of new columns and rows, no longer linked to the source tables or metadata. You are exactly right that the query returns a "flat" result. This is what I've just described. Please refer to the link above, it contains your answer.

Comment: It does not contain an answer because I cannot join them during the sql, it requires separate SQL for Customer and Orders, but no way to LINK them.  It answers how to do something different, I have seen that (I did do a search first...).  What good is building the relation AFTER selecting a million orders that do not relate to the customer I have in hand?   If the answer is 'there is no way', I can at a MINIMUM run through the reader and build the dataset myself I guess, I just was hoping for a more automated way.

Comment: @LBencic If you need to join the tables after you get your dataset, you can use .Net's LINQ to Join the tables as you see fit and filter data too. It can be a little more complicated (in my opinion) to work with Joins and possibly subqueries and such in C# or VB on the backend instead of finding a way to do most of it in SQL, but in your case it may be necessary, that's my two cents anyway.

Comment: I need to join the tables DURING the sql, before I fill the dataset.  Because the child table should only get records that relate to a field on the parent.  With separate SQL, i can only loop through the results of SQL1 / Parent, and perform a separate SQL 2 to the Child with the Where Child.Field = Parent.Field, and that is not efficient.